# Is Sendgrid have same layout for all email clients?

Tags: email, cakephp, sendgrid

I have a console programme in CakePhp that send email to many users.But there is problem that different email clients have different look for same email.Yahoo have exactly the right layout according to my code but gmail has bad layout.

Now my question is that if i use sendgrid service for sending email then layout problem will be solved or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendGrid doesn't do anything special to ensure that your email looks good, but there are other tools for that such as litmus.com. The main thing you want to make sure you do is to use inline CSS styles; many clients don't process  rules correctly unless they are inline.